# Delete Blank Rows from Column B

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying delete all rows where column B to AD (Lastrow) are blank. On my excel sheet every couple of rows or so column B to AD are blank so i am trying to delete those rows. I have been trying to use the below code:

```
Sub T()
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("B1:AC10402")
    rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

No success

Comment: is the entire row blank or just some cells is blank in those rows?

Comment: The entire row is blank besides column A.

Comment: so basically if column b to ac in any row is blank, delete it?

Comment: @pokemon_Man Ya thats correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this deletes all blank rows in column B

```
Dim LastRow, i As Integer
LastRow = activesheet.Cells(activesheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B" & i)) = 0 Then
        Range("B" & i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
```

this deletes all blank rows if column B to column AC is blank

```
Dim LastRow, i As Integer
LastRow = activesheet.Cells(activesheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B" & i & ":" & "AC" & i)) = 0 Then
        Range("B" & i & ":" & "AC" & i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: There is text is column A. But from B to last row it will be empty , so i am trying to delete those rows.

Comment: i am getting a compile error on those two codes on .rows

Comment: @pokeman_Man the second code woks well. The first one deleted my whole excel sheet ha - Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
Sub DeleteBlankRows()
Dim i As Long
Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = 10 'here you have to specify last row your table uses
For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column = 1 Then
        Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

**Little explanation**

You specified that you need check for emptiness within row, columns B through AD. This piece of code `Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` will return column of the right-most (starting from first column), non-empty cell. If whole row is empty or there's data in first column - it will return 1 - which is misleading, when you are considering `A` cloumn. But it isn't here, since we consider columns starting with `B`. So if it returns 1, it means that the row is empty and should be deleted.