# Delete Blank Columns starting at Row 2

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to delete blank columns in the worksheet from **Row 2** . If the whole column is blank i want to delete the column.

The reason i am starting from row 2 is because i have headers in row 1. Subsequently these will also be deleted if that column is blank.  How do i start from row 2?

```
Sub Delete_Cols()
 Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim iCounter As Long
    Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    For iCounter = MyRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
       If Application.CountA(Columns(iCounter).EntireColumn) = 0 Then
       Columns(iCounter).Delete
       End If
    Next iCounter
End Sub
```

I need the macro to start checking for blank columns from row 2.

Comment: @danieltakeshi - in this case, row 1 will be still deleted by `Columns(iCounter).Delete` .

Comment: Yes, now I think I understood his question (still a little confused). Because i was reading the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47162391/delete-blank-rows-from-column-b), which i wondered he was trying to fix that code. But it is completely different.

Comment: Why not Application.CountA(Columns(iCounter).EntireColumn) = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right you would like to see if the column starting with row 2 is empty and if yes, yoo would like to delete the column. If you have a header in every column your code only needs a small correction

```
Sub Delete_Cols()
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim iCounter As Long
    Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    For iCounter = MyRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
        If Application.CountA(Columns(iCounter).EntireColumn) = 1 Then
            Columns(iCounter).Delete
        End If
    Next iCounter
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `Clear` and not to `Delete`, if you want to start from Row 2. 
This is a way to go around it:

```
If Application.CountA(Columns(iCounter).EntireColumn) = 0 Then
    Range(Cells(2, iCounter), Cells(2 ^ 16, iCounter)).Clear
End If
```

It will clear the ranges from row 2 to row 65536. Probably it will work the way you want it.

Comment: @James - select the correct sheet and run it again.

Answer (score 0):

The VBA below deletes a column in your sheet if it is empty:

```
Sub DeleteEmptyColumns()
  'Updateby20140317
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim InputRng As Range
  xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
  Set InputRng = Application.Selection
  Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  For i = InputRng.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
      Set rng = InputRng.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn
      If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) = 0 Then
        rng.Delete
    End If
  Next
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```